# Is there a formalization of the link between geometry and analytical geometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, axioms, axiomatic-geometry

Geometry and algebra/calculus can be formalized by axioms.

Is there a global theory that combines both and establishes correspondences such as

- the equation of a straight line is $ax+by+c=0$,
- the length of a segment is $\sqrt{(x_b-x_a)^2+(y_b-y_a)^2}$,
- a rotation corresponds to an orthogonal transformation,
- the circumference of a unit circle is $2\pi$,

and so on. I mean not just in the numerical sense, but with an established correspondence between the equations and the geometric entities and measures as defined by Euclid.

As an application, can a geometric proof of the identity

$$\lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{\sin\theta}\theta=1$$ constitute an undisputable argument in terms of calculus ?

Comment: "the circumference of a unit circle is $2\pi$" is usually not a result. $\pi$ is defined to be the number such that that statement is true.

Comment: @Arthur: but can a solid link be made with this definition of $\pi$ and, say, the one derived from the Basel series ?

Comment: Clearly, since we have done it in the past. I don't know the fastest way from the basics, though. I guess that's what this question is about, in some sense.

Comment: "Clearly, since we have done it in the past": done what ?

Comment: "the fastest way from the basics": no, I am after "some formal way".

Comment: "done what ?" Connected the ratio of a circumference of the circle to the sum of recoprocal squares. It is a known result. Are you doubting the formality of said result (or some of the intermediate results which lead to it)? And if that's not it, then the only thing I can think of is that you want a neat, short way from one to the other. Your requirements that it be formal and rigorous doesn't change that.

Comment: "Connected the ratio of a circumference of the circle to the sum of recoprocal squares." is, of course, supposed to be "Connected the ratio between the circumference of a circle **and its radius** to the sum of recoprocal squares." I was a few seconds too late to spot it and correct it.

Comment: @Arthur: I don't understand how $\pi$, a numerical constant well-defined by a series can be related to the "length" of a circumference, which is an independently defined geometric entity (locus of constant distance). Or are you telling me that $\pi$ defines the measure of arc lengths ?

Comment: This is how I read your problem: There is one number $\pi_1$ which is _defined_ in terms of the measure of arc lengths (specifically of the circle). Then there is one number $\pi_2$ which appears in the solution to the Basel problem. You want a formal way of connecting the field of geometry which gives $\pi_1$ to the field of analysis which gives $\pi_2$, and show that $\pi_1 = \pi_2$. I know the scope of your problem is _larger_ than just this one connection, but is this a grave misrepresentation, or am I close?

Comment: @Arthur: yes, that's it. Alternatively, it could be that with some axiomatisation of geometry, $\pi_1\ne\pi_2$, so that $\pi_1=\pi_2$ should be added as an axiom to narrow down the geometry we accept.

Comment: You can find the machine checked proofs of the answer to your first two bullets in our paper:  "Formalization of the Arithmetization of Euclidean Plane
Geometry and Applications" https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01483457/file/extended-arithmetization.pdf

Comment: You can find some machine checked proofs about your fourth bullet (link between several definitions of Pi) in Bertot and Allais: "Views of PI: Definition and computation" https://jfr.unibo.it/article/view/4343

Answer (score 1):

The "basics" are developed by Hilbert into [*The Foundations of Geometry* (1899)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms#Editions_and_translations_of_Grundlagen_der_Geometrie).

The book states the axioms for plane Euclidean geometry.

Hilbert defines the fundamental geometrical object : *segment*.

Indipendently, he states the laws for real numbers.

Finally, Hilbert develop an "algebra of segments", i.e defines the operations of *sum* and *multiplication* of segments, showing that they satisfy the previous laws.

With all this machinery in place :

> To the system of segments already discussed, let us now add a second system. We will distinguish the segments of the new system from those of the former one by means of a special sign, and will call them “*negative*” segments in contradistinction to the “*positive*” segments already considered. If we introduce also the segment $O$, which is determined by a single point, and make other appropriate conventions, then all of the rules [previously] deduced for calculating with real numbers will hold equally well here for calculating with segments.
>
> In a plane $\alpha$, we now take two straight lines cutting each other in $O$ at right angles as the fixed axes of rectangular co-ordinates, and lay off from $O$ upon these two straight lines the arbitrary segments $x$ and $y$. We lay off these segments upon the one side or upon the other side of $O$, according as they are positive or negative. At the extremities of $x$ and $y$, erect perpendiculars and determine the point $P$ of their intersection. The segments $x$ and $y$ are called the *co-ordinates* of $P$. Every point of the plane $\alpha$ is uniquely determined by its co-ordinates $x, y$, which may be positive, negative, or zero.
>
> Let $l$ be a straight line in the plane $\alpha$, such that it shall pass through $O$ and also through a point $C$ having the co-ordinates $a, b$. If $x, y$ are the co-ordinates of any point on $l$, it follows at once from theorem 22 [ratio between corresponding sides of *similar* triangles] that
>
> > $a : b = x : y ,$
>
> or
>
> > $bx − ay = 0 ,$
>
> is the [equation of the straight line $l$](https://books.google.it/books?id=53Z-CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA27) .

---

See also : Gerard Venema, [Foundations of Geometry (Pearson, 2011)](https://books.google.it/books?id=byfMygAACAAJ).

Comment: Very interesting. This is the kind of formalisation I am looking for. As I understand this settles the case of distance and similarity. I am also interested to know how the measure of angles is defined and the connection to the trigonometric functions, in the frame of orthogonal projections and entire series.